# Fix Page Header Height in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Is it possible to fix the height of page header or any other solutions?

My problem is I need to do this list of persons in page header

```
Boy       Janna
Girl      Leo
Ana       Erick
Mina      Carlo
Lea       Shena
```

But it must be like this

```
(for page 1)
Boy       Janna
Girl      Leo
Ana       Erick
```

```
(next page)
Mina      Carlo
Lea       Shena
```

If number of person is **6 or lower** it will **only appear in first page** (if two page report the second page must have blank person). If the number of person is **more than 6** the **number 7 person and up will appear to next pages** and so on. 
**The maximum row is 3 per page**

This Sub report is in Page header in main report 
I put this code in supress of Sub Report for Persons. If I don't tick the Can Grow and adjust the text box (it only shows 6 names) and other names are now missing and not appearing in the next page. If I tick can grow and remove the below supression code what happens is it shows repeated name each page.

```
if PageNumber = 1 then
  false

else if PageNumber = TotalPageCount then
  true

else 
  true
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you making sure how many pages are going to be present in the report?

Comment: I don't know but if one page the total number of person display is 6 or less than 6 and if more than one page the other person will be displayed to the next page

Comment: I think your requirment is something difficult... because page header is a dynamic component that will be created as data spans across pages and which is not in user control... Can you have the same functionality in some other sections other than page header and what is the exact requirment

Comment: ok if in page header is difficult I will put it in PROD_ID group but how can I make the group header height be fix and show only 6 or less passenger in first page and if passenger is more than 6 the other passenger will show in next page. Still per page will show 6 passenger.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do it in group header or footer and the process you followed won't give you correct results. Follow below process.

In grouper header or footer take a sub report and place only those fields in the sub report that you want to display.

In sub report place the field in detail section and then go to

```
Right click Details --> section expert --> paging --> tick the check box visible records
```

In the space provided input number of records you want to view per page and no go to preview.

You can see those many records per page in group.

This is working solution I tried group header and group footer of a group.

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll try your solution